# Not able to get JSON Data from API URL using Rest Assured and JAVA

Tags: java, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the following URL: **http://example.com/stocks/rank_by_category/json/C:A:5/5** 
I have tried using the below code but it is returning blank data. 
I have tried fetching the data through Postman and it is returning data correctly.

```
@Test
String vgm_str = RestAssured.given().accept(ContentType.JSON).when()
                 .get(new URI("http://example.com/stocks/rank_by_category/json/C:A:5/5"))
                 .thenReturn().asString();
System.out.println(vgm_str);
```

Through Postman the response is

```
{
"Com": [
    {
        "rank_cat": "aa",
        "rank_category_text": "as",
        "score_passed": "A",
        "income_score": null,
        "momentum_score": "dd",
        "growth_score": "A",
        "value_score": "A",
        "composite_score": "A",
        "rnum": "9",
        "name": "Orient Overseas International Ltd.",
        "ticker": "ss",
        
    }
]
}
```

Could anyone please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Is example.com a real domain?

Comment: @HopeyOne No example.com is not a real domain, as the real domain is a official domain. Do you need the real domain name? I have tested the api URL in postman and it is returning data.

Comment: no you probably don't want to post the real domain but you need to edit your question to include more information. What have you tried? Have you tried your request with other tools like postman? Post any logs showing any errors, response headers. Does the line `System.out.println(vgm_str);` print anything?

Comment: @HopeyOne Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried with postman and it is returning the json  data as normal. There are no errors and when printing "vgm_str" it is only returning "[]" blank.

Comment: @HopeyOne In the URL "C:A:5/5"  does this format is affecting anyway?

Comment: Can you try `then().log().all()`?

Comment: @HopeyOne Yes I have tried `.then().log().all().toString();` here is the response     `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 08:11:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
server-id: w3-1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 2
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json

[
    
]
io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl@7efb53af`

Comment: @HopeyOne Is there any solution to the issue?

Comment: `200 OK` means the server returned the response without error. `Content-Length: 2` in the header means the response contains only the empty array. If your response is different using postman to the same URI then there is something different about the request causing the server to provide a different response. You could try postman to capture and proxy the [request](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/). That way you can compare it to your postman request.

Comment: Yes in POSTMAN I am receiving the full JSON request. My actual target is to, capture the data and do assertion with the Site data through Selenium. Is there any other way of getting the response through JAVA.

Comment: It is working now, just added RestAssured.given().urlEncodingEnabled(false)